# Docker - docker-compose error bind to port 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to setup Docker for a PHP environment and migration to 7.4.

Getting the following error running docker-compose up...

```
PS E:\Projects\PHP Migration to 7.4> docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/1
 - Container phpmigrationto74-web-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
Attaching to phpmigrationto74-web-1
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

The docker-compose.yml file in the above directory contains:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Most likely my institution has port 80 blocked or reserved.

So I tried:

```
PS E:\Projects\PHP Migration to 7.4> docker run --detach --publish 81:80 --name webserver
```

and opening a browser at:

http://localhost:81/

Is successful showing:

```
Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
```

How do I setup using port 81, assuming that is possible?

Comment: "How do I setup using port 81, assuming that is possible?" - in docker-compose? If you meant this, then just change this line `- "80:80"`, to this `- "81:80"`. In your docker-compose.yml

Comment: I get Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint phpmigrationto74-web-1 (97b04fbf531de9ad1f574c4b433da1de0736f802ab9b95f9d173e4b6801da051): Bind for 0.0.0.0:81 failed: port is already allocated

Comment: Hm, weird. Have you tried restarting docker? What is output of `docker ps`? Are you on windows or linux? Also, while researching, I found out that there is a [github issue dedicated to this error message](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2722). Seems like one of the many tips there could help.

Comment: maybe other web servers like your system's apache or nginx are set on port 80. make sure that they are stopped. then allow nginx to use port 80 in firewall

Comment: Using Windows 10.  There shouldn’t be anything using port 81.  Have started Docker, no difference.  Have installed and run EasyPHP DevServer on port 8080 OK with PHP 7.4.  So will possibly stick with that for this project.